# How to hide the separate error log window in DBeaver?

Tags: sql, dbeaver

A few weeks ago I detached the error log within the editor as a separate window; I was just seeing what was going to happen.

Now I can't put it back and I get two separate error log windows. One that is the original detached window and another that's still within the editor. I can't find any option to reattach it to the single Dbeaver window/editor in attempt to revert it to what it was before.

The yellow bar in the picture is the window I'm referring to. It's just a little annoying for a new window to be produced every time I get an error. I've tried to look for toggles in the preferences menu but haven't seen anything that stands out to be the problem. Nor can I just drag and drop back it into the editor.

[image: error windows]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like after an update you can't merge it to any of the bottom windows , but can keep it as a tabbed window like this.
[image: See Image]

Comment: This is definitely better than a whole other window. Thank you!